# Building Dictionary in Python as a Function

Tags: python, dictionary, arduino, pycharm

Hi everyone~~ :) I have an Arduino Uno sending sensor data over USB to PyCharm (Python IDE), after which I have to compile these data and write to a CSV file for machine learning later.

I am trying to build a dictionary in Python as a function as seen below:

```
def readData():  # reads inputs from Arduino
   try:
     datastring = arduino.readline()
   except:
     pass
 return datastring

def build_dictionary(): # function to build dictionary
     incomingdata = readData()

    for incomingdata in arduino:
      incomingdata = incomingdata.strip()

    if incomingdata:
        datasplit = incomingdata.split(',')
        i = 0
        temperature = datasplit[i]
        i = i + 1
        humidity = datasplit[i]
        i = i + 1
        light = datasplit[i]
        i = 0
        dic = {'Temp': temperature, 'Humidity': humidity, 'Light': light}
```

When I printed some parts of the dictionary, "dic", immediately after "dic = {...}, as in:

```
print "dic['Temp']: ", dic['Temp']
```

I was able to obtain output normally (i.e. PyCharm printed everything Arduino sent to it). However, when I did the following:

```
def build_dictionary(): # function to build dictionary
     incomingdata = readData()

    for incomingdata in arduino:
      incomingdata = incomingdata.strip()

    if incomingdata:
        datasplit = incomingdata.split(',')
        i = 0
        temperature = datasplit[i]
        i = i + 1
        humidity = datasplit[i]
        i = i + 1
        light = datasplit[i]
        i = 0
        global dic
        dic = {'Temp': temperature, 'Humidity': humidity, 'Light': light}
   return dic

while True:
    print "dic['Temp']: ", dic['Temp']
```

the output became:

```
dic['Temp']:  24.00 
dic['Temp']:  25.00
```

Only the first 2 outputs were printed strangely. A check on the Arduino board showed that it was still sending information to PyCharm (Python) but they were just not getting printed out.

May I ask where did I go wrong here?

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Perhaps output equal to the previous line was suppressed. So only if the Temp changes to something other than 25.00 will a new line be shown.

Comment: You have the line: `incomingdata = readData()`, but then you have `for incomingdata in arduino:`. Firstly why do you throw away the first `incomingdata`? And secondly what is `arduino` in the second line?

Comment: @153957 I see. May I ask what changes should I make in this case to prevent this from happening? Thank you~ :)

Comment: @quamrana This is because I am trying to put the incoming serial data from Arduino into a variable, called "incomingdata", after which I would like to remove all spaces and newline characters in the serial stream. "arduino" in the second line is referenced to: serial.Serial(), where 'serial' is 'arduino' here.

Comment: Ok, now it sounds like you just throw **all** the data away: `for incomingdata in arduino:` throws away everything except the last line.

Comment: @quamrana What do you mean by 'throw everything except the last line'? If I want the outcome to be:

For the stream of data coming in with Arduino to Python, remove all whitespaces and newline characters.

How should I write this? May I have some hints please? Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to read a line from the serial port and then process that line, and then go back and get a new line and so on:

```
def readData(): # read just one line from arduino
    # simplified
    return arduino.readline()

def build_dictionary(incomingdata): # function to build dictionary
    dic = {}
    incomingdata = incomingdata.strip()
    if incomingdata:
        datasplit = incomingdata.split(',')
        temperature = datasplit[0]
        humidity = datasplit[1]
        light = datasplit[2]
        dic = {'Temp': temperature, 'Humidity': humidity, 'Light': light}
   return dic

while True:
    dic = build_dictionary(readData())
    print(dic)
```

**Note:**

This code loops round forever. It has no way to stop (unless you press ctrl-C)

**Update:**

Using a counter to break after a number of samples:

```
for _ in range(9999):
    dic = build_dictionary(readData())
    print(dic)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for your kind help! :) I do not intend to stop because Python which will be hosted on Raspberry Pi later, will always acquire data indefinitely from Arduino. I will think of a way to "break" the file, maybe through a loop counter (will this work, may I ask? :)) after a certain number of data are stored. 

This is because I would like to store 10,000 samples of sensor data, before I close that file, and then use it to perform machine learning. (:

Comment: Just to clarify, in the function, "build_dictionary(incomingdata)", should there be a call to the readData() function? For example: "incomingdata = readData()".

Comment: The way I design functions is for them to have high cohesion low coupling. So `build_dictionary` takes the parameter of `incomingdata` and processes that. It is then not coupled to `readData()`. However you will see the outer loop does the call to `readData()` and passes the result to `build_dictionary`.

Comment: Thank you so much, @quamrana~ I will study your code carefully and will update you again~ :) Thank you once again! ^^